# Restoring an OpenEdge v10 database into v11

Tags: openedge, database-restore, progress-db

I am brand new to the OpenEdge database platform and so far am really struggling. I have a client who has given me a backup of his database (a single `.bak` file) which was taken from OpenEdge v10. I only have a OpenEdge v11 database server.

We do not own OpenEdge or anything, so as far as I am aware getting my hands on v10 is probably impossible. Our client just wants me to poke around in the database to see what I can find, so I'm not prepared to put too much money into this.

When I try to do the restore, I get:

```
C:\Progress\OpenEdge\bin>prorest.bat E:\Progress\ServicePro\ServicePro "E:\Progress\svcpro_l.bak"
OpenEdge Release 11.3 as of Wed Jul 17 16:46:26 EDT 2013
Start of extending target DB to needed size... (9432)
Version number mismatch, backup has 4246, database has 4269. (16691)
Restore failed. (1618)
!!! ERROR - Database restore utility FAILED !!! (8564)
```

I have searched as much as I can and found this [KB article](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000029439?retURL=/apex/progresskbsearch&popup=false), but it seems to not apply to restoring a database, rather a copied database.

How can I restore a Progress OpenEdge database backup that was taken from v10 into v11?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with backups is that they are intended to be restored by the same version that created them.  On the same machine architecture and OS too.  You cannot use them to directly move from one version to another or between platforms.  (Although some flexibility is sometimes found it isn't supported and won't help you in this case.)

It sounds like it must not be too big of a database.  So have them send you a zipped copy of the database.  All of the database.  Make sure that they truncate the bi file first.  On their box:

```
proutil dbname -C truncate bi
```

Then:

```
prostrct list dbname
```

This will create dbname.st -- in that file is a list of every file that needs to be in the zip archive.  Make sure that your client gets them **all**.

Unzip it (life will be easier if you use the same path names) and then run:

```
proutil dbname -C conv1011
```

You will now have a version 11 database ready to take a look at.

Comment: Ok cool. It's a 1.1GB database, so not that big. I will ask them for this, if they know how to get it.

Comment: Is `proutil dbname -C truncate bi` a destructive command? Will their database still be usable at their end after doing this?

Comment: No, it's semi-normal maintenance.  Often done after a large process generates a lot of activity.  Truncating the bi ("redo log") doesn't need to be done all the time but it is necessary before changing versions.

Comment: I got there eventually with your advice; but because of the way the files from my client got here, I had to run a `102b05_dbutil prostrct unlock svcpro_l` then `proutil svcpro_l -C conv1011` and then `proutil svcpro_l -C idxbuild ALL -TB 24 -TM 32 -B 1000 -SG 64` but I eventually got a usable database. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find someone with a v10 license to do the restore, then convert the restored db to a v11 db, and then you can use your v11 system to look through the resulting db.

Comment: Actually older versions of the db-utils are included in the installation. Of exactly this reason.

Comment: Do tell - I've never seen these older utils in the systems I've worked on.

Answer (score 0):

See this entry in the Progress Knowledgebase. Look specifically at paragraph 2. Even if youre not exactly upgrading from 10.2 you should be able to modify the steps.

**Always make sure you save a copy of the original backup before you start messing around with it. You can potentially destroy it...**

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000031654?q=Version+10+utilities+in+version+11&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1

Comment: How does any of that apply to a backup file? They all seem to expect an actual database to work with...

Comment: The 4th bullet in the 2nd part:   4.  Backup the database:
Example command to backup the database using 102dbutils: 
$DLC/102b05_dbutil -C probkup <dbname> <dbname>-10.bkp -- replace "probkup" with "prorest" and "dbname-10.bkp" with "dbname.bak" and you will have a v10 database, then proceed with converting from that point.